# Php include method and Jquery load method?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have 3 folders:

- Admin
- Home
- Profile

Each folders have different **css**, **js**, and **php** files in it with more than 1000 lines, so that's why I kept them in separate folders.

But now I want to manage the whole indexes is one, so I made another php file with name `All.php` and I made a radio button in it to show and hide these three files (admin, home and profile).

I have tried to include these files by `?php include(filename.php) ?` method, but the css wasn't working with it.

Then I copied the **css** and js link files from the `Admin.php` to `All.php` and it was working fine.

But the problem is when I copied more files(css and js links) with different names to `All.php`, some conflicts appear, and the style of `Admin.php` got shattered.

I don't know whats wrong with it, and it's same with `jquery.load() method`. The **css** doesn't work in `All.php` when I load a file from three of these, and when here too I copied the links and sources then, many of the functionalities were not working.

Comment: wut? Could you maybe add some relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

Look up [cascade](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade), [inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance) and [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). You possibly have conflicting selectors in css files. What kind of functionalities are not working? Need code for that!